# Rendering animation to movie

Tags: iphone, animation, rendering, uiimage, movieclip

I have a serious problem with Core Animation in combination with the AV Foundation.

I want to render the animation of several UIImages to a movie file. The animation of the images should only be the change from one image to the next, just like shown here http://appsamuck.com/day2.html. But I don't want to display this animation but render it to a common movie file.

I know it is possible to create movie files using the AV Foundation, but I don't get it. I don't know how to set up the animation so I can save the movie file.

Currently I am using the code shown here [Need hints for using iPhone SDK's AVMutableVideoComposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401313/need-hints-for-using-iphone-sdks-avmutablevideocomposition), but the difference is that I don't want to render a shake animation but the image change.

Can somebody help me or give me a hint which Core Animation class I must use? I looks like the AV Foundation needs a Core Animation object, but the common way to implement the image change animation is using the UIImageView class.

C YA