# UIImages to movie with AV Foundation

Tags: iphone, uiimage, movie, avfoundation

I have a serious problem with the AV Foundation.

I want to render the animation of several UIImages to a movie file. I just want to make a movie file in which the images are changed every 1/x second.

Currently I am using the code shown here [Need hints for using iPhone SDK's AVMutableVideoComposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401313/need-hints-for-using-iphone-sdks-avmutablevideocomposition), but the difference is that I don't want to render a shake animation but the image change.

Can somebody help me or give me a hint which Core Animation class I must use? I looks like the AV Foundation needs a Core Animation object, but the common way to implement the image change animation is using the UIImageView class.